# При запуске WEBSOCKET перестаёт работать FETCH

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, fetch

С толкнулся со странной проблемой, когда 
я открываю соединение с `вебсокетом`, то всё ок, всё работает, сообщения приходят. Но когда я посылаю любой запрос к `php` `(fetch)` он находится в состоянии `pedding`, так же как и сам `websocket`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогает только перезапуск локального сервера

Это код, который подключается к `websocket`

```js
let conn = new WebSocket('ws://colorshop:8777');
// пробовал много вариантов
//let conn = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8777');
//let conn = new WebSocket('ws://colorshop:8777/WSchat.php');
//let conn = new WebSocket('ws://colorshop:8777/core/classes/SocketChat');
// Но всё равно не помогает


// send only if connected
let wsSend = function(data) {
  if (!conn.readyState) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      wsSend(data);
    }, 100);
  } else {
    conn.send(data);
  }
};

// if connection is established
conn.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onclose = function(e) {
  console.log("Connection is closed");
};
conn.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("ERROR:" + e.message);
};

// if a message arrived
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
};
```

С помощью этого кода открывается новое соединение

```js
public function openSocket() {
  $conn = parent::conn();
  $userId = $_SESSION['userId']; //userId

  $server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
      new WsServer(
        new SocketChat()
      )
    ),
    8777
  );

  $server - > run();
}
```

А это сам класс с реализацией методов

```js
<?php namespace ColorCore;
require 'W:\domains\colorShop\vendor\autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class SocketChat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            //if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
                // $client->send($msg);
            //}
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: в консоли браузер (если через него соединение) какие-то ошибки есть?

Comment: нету. НУ как нету, есть предупреждения, но они не влияют

Comment: Есть идеи? если что у меня openServer

Comment: Вообще без какого-либо кода сложно понять что случилось.

Comment: А у меня автомобиль не едет. Сначала нормально, а потом так ггррхх-тык-тык и все. В чем может быть причина? Намек - без кода ничем помочь не можем)

Comment: Я добавил код, надеюсь поможет

Comment: Я так думаю, что проблема, что websocket не даёт fetch обратиться к php, так как уже идёт обращение

Comment: Запуск сервера, надеюсь, находится не на той страницы, которую вы перезагружаете?

Comment: всм? У меня SPA сайт, по сути всё одна страница. И я ещё использую вебпак. У меня есть папка с фронтендом, к примеру на рабочем  столе, и есть папка в папке domains

Comment: Стоп, а какого сервера? У меня сайт на таком адресе http://127.0.0.1:8080, на нём же я запускаю сокет, только порт другой

Comment: @ArchDemon есть идеи

Comment: Если у вас на стартовой странице, с которой грузится весь SPA ещё выполняется и `openSocket();`, то это беда-печаль

Comment: ну у меня есть единый js файл(объединено через импорт) там есть функция чат ,в которой когда через fetch из бд достанутся сообщения и вставятся, выполняется тот код, который в самом верху (создаю новый сокет). Даже если в php я не выполню функцию openSocket, то всё-равно у меня перестают работать все обращения к php(кстати даже без перезагрузки, просто, если после подключения к сокету обратится через fetch к php, то вот не работает) Следовательно проблема в js, либо в пути. Кстати, к какому файлу нужно указывать путь? структура такая https://ibb.co/31V1tPR  И насколько я знаю в консоли нужно

Comment: запустить файл с сокетом, но когда я пишу php SocketChat.php, то ничего не происходит

Comment: нашел ещё то, что обращение всё-таки идёт, но оно никак не завершится https://ibb.co/1fxQXry

Comment: @ArchDemon заходи пж почаще

Comment: можешь дать свой вк?

Comment: Ничего и не должно происходить, если не подцеплены логи. Процесс должен висеть в памяти. Лучше запускать `php SocketChat.php &`. Советую все события писать в лог. Тогда станет понятно на каком этапе что идёт не так.

Comment: у меня все ошибки если что выводятся в окно браузера, там ничего нет, а где найти файлы логов я нигде не нашёл, что как-то странно) вот мой вк https://vk.com/vlad_rogov2000

Comment: и даже если запустить в консоли чат, когда пишешь сообщение и отправляешь его, то в консоли оно отображается. Но fetch всё равно не выполняется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хаха, череp четыре дня мучения я понял, что нужно просто открыть соединение с `websocket` через JS, а в php лезть вообще не надо. А я сначала запускал функцию openSocket(), которая само по идеи выполняется, когда я открываю соединение `new Websocket()`

Comment: Вы опять неверно всё поняли. `openSocket()` должна быть выполнена ДО подключения через js. Причём единожды, на сервере

Comment: Ну на ютубе я смотрел обучалку, там было просто new websocket(url) url к файлу, на котором находится openSocket (Ну не сама функция, а только то, что внутри, чтобы сразу выполнилось) и всё, она будет присылать сообщения итд.  А если что-то не так, то у меня всё работает, я итак потратил 5 дней))))

Comment: Или вы неправильно поняли автора, или уровень знаний автора не столь высок, как ему это кажется. Попробуйте искать информацию из нескольких источников. В итоге найдёте автора, который и объясняет лучше и знает больше

Comment: вот раз автор https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjX1JSbdrtQ&t=189s

Comment: вот два https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vn4wiUeOTps&list=LLUndJYSJyip1gvQ95tBigZw&index=12&t=518s

Comment: ивот документация на добивку http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: @ArchDemon можешь подсказать? В ratchet вроде есть встроенный механизм создания комнат и уведомлений, но я нигде не могу найти внятного, понятного и четкого объяснения всего этого, можешь помочь?